# Continue in a try clause in Python, even if the exception is raised

Tags: python, try-catch

Is there any way to continue code execution in a try clause, even when the exception is raised?

This is the code example.

```
outer_margin = 0.125  # Default Amazon
safe_zone = 0.25  # Default Amazon
safe_spine = 0.0625  # Default Amazon
if custom_measure is not None:
    if isinstance(custom_measure, dict):
        try:
            outer_margin = custom_measure["outer_margin"]
            safe_zone = custom_measure["safe_zone"]
            safe_spine = custom_measure["safe_spine"]
        except KeyError as e:
            logger.warning("Key {} not found, default value used.".format(e))
```

All three values are optional, so the key `outer_margin` may not exist, but `safe_zone` may be present. I would like to reach `safe_zone` even if calling `outer_margin` raises an exception. Is there any way to do this in a single try/except block? Something like:

```
# Not valid syntax
try:
    outer_margin = custom_measure["outer_margin"]
try:
    safe_zone = custom_measure["safe_zone"]
except KeyError as e:
    pass
```

I already found a different solution to the case in the example, but now I am curious to know if there is a way to continue down one try/except block, even if the exception is raised.

Comment: To continue you either add code in `excpet` or `else` or `finally` block.

Comment: Seems like it'd be much easier to just use `custom_measure.get`.

Comment: Is not possible to put `safe_zone = custom_measure["safe_zone"]` before `outer_margin = custom_measure["outer_margin"]` so that the first got executed anyway?

Comment: Your second example ('not valid syntax') fails because every `try` must have an `except`; you cannot have one `except` for multiple `try`s.

Comment: Actually, I ended up putting the three default variables in a dictionary `measures`, and I used `measures.update(custom_measure)`. I was just curious about the try/except in general.

Comment: @CarlH: Off-topic nitpick, but: a `try` doesn't have to have an `except` if it has a `finally`.

Comment: You can nest another `try` block in the `except` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead of catching the `KeyError` exception.

```
if isinstance(custom_measure, dict):
    outer_margin = custom_measure.get("outer_margin")
    safe_zone = custom_measure.get("safe_zone")
    safe_spine = custom_measure.get("safe_spine")
```

if `"outer_margin"` does not exist in `custom_measure` it will be set to `None`.

You can also set another default value than `None` like this.

```
outer_margin = custom_measure.get("outer_margin", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the log, refactor the `try/except` out of there:

```
def get_with_warning(data, key, default):
    if key in data:
        return data[key]
    else:
        logger.warning("Key {} not found, default value used.".format(key))
        return default

outer_margin = get_with_warning(custom_measure, "outer_margin", 0.125)
safe_zone = get_with_warning(custom_measure, "safe_zone", 0.25)
safe_spine = get_with_warning(custom_measure, "safe_spine", 0.0625)
```

If not, then it's as easy as this:

```
outer_margin = custom_measure.get("outer_margin", 0.125)
safe_zone = custom_measure.get("safe_zone", 0.25)
safe_spine = custom_measure.get("safe_spine", 0.0625)
```